# How are variables stored in memory in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

How are variables stored in memory in the Rails console? Is there a key value store somewhere?

For example, when I open the Rails console with `rails c`, and type the following.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 7854
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.3.0 :001 > thing = "car"
 => "car" 
2.3.0 :002 > thing
 => "car" 
2.3.0 :003 >
```

`thing` is persisted in memory for the duration of the session.

Apologies if this is a newbie question, but I'm been programming for a while and I still don't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails console just uses [IRB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) behind the scenes by autoloading your entire application.

IRB is nothing but a module that evaluates all your input immediately and stores the result inside its own module.